# Asynchronously run several instances of the same function with output

Tags: python, asynchronous, python-asyncio

I am trying to build a number of Machine Learning models on a single dataset. The output of all models is then to be used in further steps. I would like the training of the models, to happen simultaneously to save time and manual labour.

I am completely new to asynchronous processing, and that has manifested itself in my code below not working. I get the error:

> sys:1 RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'level1models' was never awaited

This appears to be a fairly common issue when `await` isn't used, but wherever I place this command the error persists, and answers I find online do not seem to address functions that return values.
To provide a reproducible example I have altered my code while keeping the structure identical to the original.

```py
from time import sleep

nrs_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]


def subtract(n):
    return n - 1


async def subtract_nrs(nrs):
    # Train selected ML models
    numbers = {nr: subtract(nr) for nr in nrs}
    sleep(50)

    # Loop to check if all models are trained
    while True:
        print([i for i in numbers.values()])
        if [i for i in numbers.values()] != [None for _ in range(len(numbers))]:
            break
        sleep(5)
    return numbers

r = subtract_nrs(nrs_list)
print(r)
```

```
<coroutine object subtract_nrs at 0x000002A413A4C4C0>
sys:1: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'subtract_nrs' was never awaited
```

Comment: As the message says, you never awaited `subtract_nrs`. Since you want to call that as the entry point to your program, you can’t simply use await. Instead you can use `asyncio.run`. That said, your code appears to be CPU-bound, not I/O-bound. asyncio will provide you no benefit. Instead, have a look at concurrent.futures and `ProcessPoolExecutor`.

Comment: @dirn as said I am new to running asynchronously. I'd appreciate a full answer, as you're using terms I am not familiar with

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anytime you create a coroutine (here when you call `subtract_nrs`) but don't await it, asyncio will emit the warning you received [[0](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-dev.html#asyncio-coroutine-not-scheduled)]. The wait you avoid this is by awaiting the coroutine, either via

```
await subtract_nrs(nrs_list)
```

or by using `asyncio.gather` [[1](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.gather)], which itself must be awaited

```
await asyncio.gather(subtract_nrs(nrs_list)
```

Note that here there's no value in using `asyncio.gather`. That would only come if you needed to wait for multiple coroutines at once.

Based on your code, you seem to be using `subtract_nrs` as the entry point to your program. `await` can't be used outside of an `async def`, so you need another way to wait for it. For that, you'll typically want to use `asyncio.run` [[2](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.run)]. This will handle creating, running, and closing the event loop along with waiting for your coroutine.

```
asyncio.run(subtract_nrs(nrs_list))
```

Now that we've covered all that, asyncio won't actually help you achieve your goal of simultaneous execution. asyncio never does things simultaneously; it does things concurrently [[3](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/61238)]. While one task is waiting for I/O to complete, asyncio's event loop allows another to execute. While you've stated that this is a simplified version of your actual code, the code you've provided isn't I/O-bound; it's CPU-bound. This kind of code doesn't work well with asyncio. To use your CPU-bound code and achieve something more akin to simultaneous execution, you should use processes. not asyncio. The best way to do this is with `ProcessPoolExecutor` from concurrent.futures [[4](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#processpoolexecutor)].

Comment: Thank you very much for your extensive answer. I will look into `ProcessPoolExecutor`!